# How to Start Activity inside a FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I am using fragments inside a frame layout but due to some problem i want to start an Activity inside that Frame layout. I am searching for this for quite a long time and all i get is that with Tab specs an all that. i simply wants to Start activity inside my Frame layout where all the fragments are opening

here is how i am opening my fragments and Message Activity

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new MyFeedsFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new MyPrivatePostsFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new MyProfileFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new PeopleFragment();

        break;
    case 4:

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MessagesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new FavouritesFragment();
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = new CreditsFragment();
        break;
    case 7:
        fragment = new SettingsFragment();
        break;
    case 8:
        fragment = new AboutThisAppFragment();
        break;
    case 9:
        fragment = new ContactUsFragment();
        break;
    case 10:
        fragment = new LogOutFragment();
        store.setLoginStatus(null);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        if (!fragment.isAdded()) {
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null).commit();
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);
        }
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    } else {
        Log.e("Main Activity", "error in creating fragment");
    }

}
```

i want Message Activity to be opened in Same Layout as my Fragments are
how could i do this???

any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Use layout inflators instead, you cant open a Activity inside an Activity.

Comment: `LayoutInflator infltor = (LayoutInflator) context.getSystemService(Context.Layout_Inflaor_Service);`
`View view = infltor.inflate(R.layout.your_activity_view, null);`
then use this view to display into your FrameLayout and do all the activity code in this Activity class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In android only one activity can be active... If you have activity with fragments and run another activity from one of this fragments actual activity will be paused. You can only run another Fragment or change your view in actual Activity and call your own refresh() method...

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_inflator_view, null);
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(view.getContext(), MessageActivity.class);
view.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

Comment: What is R.layout.top_bar ??

Comment: It is your inflator view(activity layout), in which you want to inflate your view.